# Python share logger configuration between modules

Tags: python, logging

I have a project containing several modules I would like to be logging into the same location. I have set a specific module apart, say `log.py`, where I have specified the formatting rules and locations where I want the logs to be written.

Until now I have been importing the logger I have created in `log.py` into modules requiring using it and was calling them from there, as specified in [python logging howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules)

Now I want to change my logger's name in every module I import it into, to be able to tell from which module a specific message came.

What would be the best way to do it? Should I subclass my logger and redefine logger's name with the module's `__name__` is there a better way to do it?

Here is an element of my logger definition:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('main_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Here is an example of how I use it:

```
from log_behavior import logger as log

[....]
log.info('mymessage')
```

Answer (score 0):

Logging config is persistant as far as I know anyway so as far as config this should work for all submodules.

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(module)s-%(levelname)s: %(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('project.logging_behaviour')
```

further formatting options are found here
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

I don't know if it's necessary but it's good practice to name your loggers the same as you would name a module absolutely. example. `project.logging_behaviour`, `project.sub_module.sub_sub_module` etc.

Comment: The problem is that I first create a logger with a `logging.getLogger('my_logger')`, and then configure that logger. Without it, I cannot set handlers. I want to sublass that configuration, just changing the name, but calling the entire configuration routine is a bit long in every module.

Comment: What I'm saying is create a global basicConfig from logging and that should persist to loggers you create afterwoulds. You shouldn't even need to import logging_behaviour more than once aslong as you import logging in each module you want to log in. Setting configuration in logging instead of per-logger should fix that issue.

Comment: The problem is that for me basicConfig does not provide enough option, so I have to use methods reserved for logger instances. I guess in the end I will be importing a logger generating function wherever I need it.

Comment: What settings do you need in basicConfig? You only asked for logging module name? Check here to see the different options in basicConfig https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig.